# ngAnimate - How to Remove NgLeave Added Delay?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, ng-animate

I'm building an angularJs application that should have a div appear and disappear by expanding and shrinking it's containing div. I'm using ngAnimate to control the animations with the special "ng-" css classes. the demo seems to be working ,but there is a strange delay in the ng-leave command. In my example the div begins growing immediately when you release the mouse on the button. However, when closing the div there is a very noticable time delay between when the button is clicked and when the div starts shrinking. You can see the issue here:

http://jsfiddle.net/evoilliot/7tb4g/

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="AppCtrl">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="showDiv" id="showDiv" />
        <label for="showDiv">Toggle DIV</label>
        <div id="my-div" ng-if="showDiv" class="animate-if">He ben voilà, ça fonctionne !</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

_

```
#my-div {
    background-color: cornflowerblue;
    /* pour l'ex, on met une hauteur au div, pour qu'il soit suffisament
    haut pour le voir bien... */
    height: 200px;
}
/*
Pour dire en CSS3 ce qui devra être animé :
Angular ajoute dynamiquement des classes CSS.
La transition se fait soit entre ng-enter et ng-enter-active
ou entre ng-leave et ng-leave-active.
*/
 .animate-if.ng-enter, .animate-if.ng-leave {
    -webkit-transition: 1s linear all;
    -moz-transition: 1s linear all;
    -ms-transition: 1s linear all;
    -o-transition: 1s linear all;
    transition: 1s linear all;
}
/* du début de l'entrée */
 .animate-if.ng-enter {
    max-height: 0;
    opacity: 0;
}
/* à la fin de l'entrée */
 .animate-if.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
    max-height: 999px;
    opacity:1;
}
/* du début de la sortie */
 .animate-if.ng-leave {
    max-height: 999px;
    opacity:1;
}
/* à la fin de la sortie */
 .animate-if.ng-leave.ng-leave-active {
    max-height: 0;
    opacity:1;
}
```

Is this a bug in ngAnimate? Am I just doing something wrong here?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The reason this is happening is because your containing div has a height of 200px but your animation is growing the internal div to 999px. When you trigger the shrinking animation, it appears to be delayed because you can't see the extra 799px going away. If you change your "max-height" to 200px in each of your animations, it should perform correctly.

Answer (score 0):

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Netron/7tb4g/343/)

Fix delay solution:

Put cubic-bezier(0, 1, 0, 1) transition function for element.

```
.text {
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 0;
  transition: max-height 0.5s cubic-bezier(0, 1, 0, 1);
  &.full {
    max-height: 1000px;
    transition: max-height 1s ease-in-out;
}
```